# Why htaccess redirects "in loop"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js, webpack

I am using rewrites with .htaccess
in this way:

```
RewriteEngine in

RewriteRule ^ administer? admin.html

RewriteRule ^ users? user.html
```

In the way it works correctly, but in the users the rewrite "in loop"

I'm using VueJS for the frontend and when compiling with webpack the project generates an `index` file and a folder `user` after I change the name to the index by user.html

and when the user.html asks for the files in the 'user' folder, the latter are also rewritten with user.html

causing the following error

> Syntax error not detected: unexpected signal <
>
> Syntax error not detected: unexpected signal <
>
> Syntax error not detected: unexpected signal <

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line of code on your htaccess file, above `RewriteRule` line.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Its make the `RewriteRule` work only if the url not targeted to file or directory.

I don't have reason why `user/filename` give you `user.html` except if you write `users/filename` or even `users/anything/another` it will give you the `user.html`